# ggplot2 geombar() and binwidth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm starting to use ggplot and trying this [example](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_histogram.html):

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(6298) 
diamonds_small <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ] 
hist_cut <- ggplot(diamonds_small, aes(x=price, fill=cut))
hist_cut + geom_bar() # defaults to stacking
```

on my data:

```
a4<-structure(list(MAACP = c(2.81, 2.28, 2.38, 3.96, 1.99, 4.69, 
3.07, 3.41, 4.18, 1.67, 3.88, 2.89, 3.32, 4.15, 5.53, 2.19, 2.36, 
5.07, 3.18, 1.58, 2.81, 3.09, 4.9, 3.69, 3.48, 4.58, 4.54, 3.42, 
2.92, 3.83, 3.42, 2.51, 2.95, 3.97, 2.95, 5.55, 5.54, 3.39, 0, 
2.06, 5.21, 2.64, 5.66, 2.15, 3.87, 4.09, 2.81, 5.19, 3.55, 5.17, 
3.55, 2.19, 3.51, 4.9, 4.95, 2.91, 3.61, 3.06, 3.02, 3.49, 3.14, 
4.23, 4.11, 2.36, 2.81, 2.82, 2.94, 4.17, 4.14, 4.35, 3.52, 3.35, 
5.45, 3.41, 4.31, 4.31, 2.45, 3.35, 4.11, 3.21, 2.52, 4.91, 3.92, 
4.84, 2.84, 2.95, 2.98, 3.67, 4.75, 3.62, 2.88, 3.09, 3.36, 3.29, 
2.47, 3.59, 3.59, 2.6, 1.85, 5.06), type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("MAACP", 
"type"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Unfortunately, I can't get the plot to display an histogram.

```
hist_cut<-ggplot(a4,aes(x="MAACP",fill=type),binwidth=.1)
hist_cut+geom_bar()
```

Changing the `binwidth` doesn't make a difference:

```
hist_cut<-ggplot(a4,aes(x="MAACP",fill=type),binwidth=.1)
hist_cut+geom_bar(binwidth=0.1)
```

Comment: I'm confused. You don't show any code that could produce an histogram. You typically would use `geom_histogram`.

Comment: @roland: thanks, but look at the example midway through the page I linked to. (just below the fifth line of code I reproduced, it's the one you get if you `ctrl-F` for `fill=cut`). I want a plot like that, whatever it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, seems like `geom_bar` produces an histogram by default, when only passed an x variable. Didn't know this and don't really like it.

Anyway:

1. Don't quote variable names if you don't use `aes_string`.
2. Pass `binwidth` to `geom_bar`, which passes it to `stat_bin`.

Like this:

```
hist_cut <- ggplot(a4, aes(x = MAACP, fill = type))
hist_cut + geom_bar(binwidth = .1)
```

Comment: binwidth is not accepted in geom_bar(). Can you clarify in what condition it accepts and when it may not? @roland

Comment: There have been two major version increases for ggpot2 since this answer was written. It's not applicable anymore. Nowadays you'd need `hist_cut + geom_bar(binwidth = 100, stat = "bin") ` to produce a histogram. And, as I wrote, `binwidth` is actually a parameter of `stat_bin`. Of course, you shouldn't use `geom_bar` to produce a histogram. You should use `geom_histogram`.